# python ctypes.WinDLL usage works but no result

Tags: python, winapi, dll

Trying to use win dll to manipulate open windows.

```
import ctypes
user32 = ctypes.WinDLL ("user32")
print(user32.FindWindowExA(None,None,None,"FileZilla"))
```

It prints 0 but FileZilla is running now.
Same library works in Java with Native.loadLibrary.
Lib seems to be loaded, because it prints error when calling FindWindowExA with wrong number of args.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code will work under 32 bit Python, but not under 64 bit Python. The reason being that you need to define the types of the arguments. You get away with not doing so in a 32 bit process by luck rather than design.

Furthermore, there seems very little point, in my opinion, in limiting yourself to the ANSI interface. You may as well get into the habit of using the native Unicode interface to Win32.

All of which leads to this:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

user32 = ctypes.WinDLL("user32")
user32.FindWindowExW.restype = wintypes.HWND
user32.FindWindowExW.argtypes = [wintypes.HWND, wintypes.HWND, wintypes.LPCWSTR, 
    wintypes.LPCWSTR]
print(user32.FindWindowExW(None, None, None, "FileZilla"))
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. But. First, I noticed that you use FindWindowExW (which works) istead of FindWindowExA (doesn't work) - what is the difference? Second, not working this, suppose should close the found window: user32.CloseWindow(user32.FindWindowExW(None,None,None,"FileZilla"))

Comment: CloseWindow only minimizes successfully. Now found the DestroyWindow function but it has no effect

Comment: I explained why I used the W function in the answer. I'm not going to attempt to answer other questions that you now ask in comments. I answered the question you asked. If that doesn't satisfy you I'm sorry.

Comment: I'm sorry for my thoughtlessness, you helped me so much! Further questions I'm gonna ask in new threads.